# Overloading the way c++ read class

Tags: c++

My custom class

```cpp
class Object {
    public:
        Object &operator=(const char *str) {
            str_val_ = std::string(str);
            return *this;
        }
        std::string str_val_;
};
```

What I expect to reach

```cpp
int main() {
    Object obj = "string";
    // Is there a way to assign obj to string directly?
    std::string str = obj;
}
```

I currently use a function `getValue()` to get the exact string value in the class. 
Is it possible to change the way c++ read a class?

Comment: Are you just looking for user-defined conversions, or are you actually trying to reimplement std::variant?

Comment: Are you looking for ways to read class members from an `std::istream`?

Comment: It seems as though you are [looking for this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews no unfortunately.

Comment: Side note: `Object obj = "string";` is an initialization. It requires a constructor that accepts `const char *`. The assignment operator cannot help you here. It's only useful after initialization.

Comment: @user4581301 so the assignment operator only works on `Object obj; obj="string";`?

Comment: @kswang correct

Comment: @user4581301 does std::variant works on `std::string str; str = obj;`? In my case it throws `error: ambiguous overload for "operator="`

Comment: I'd need to see how you are using `std::variant` to be able to answer that. You removed the need for `std::variant` when you edited the question and left only `std::string` as the only member of `Object`. Recommendation: get the ability to `std::string str = obj` working with just the `string` member, and then ask a new question about how to get it working with multiple objects. I think you'll come back to my now-deleted comment that you cannot overload based on return type.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [user-defined conversion function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator):

```cpp
Object::operator std::string() const
{
    return str_val_;
}
```

Then you can cast `Object` to string:

```cpp
std::string s = static_cast<std::stirng>(obj);
```

Or simply:

```cpp
std::string s = obj;
```